# com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException when running in GWT Dev Mode

Tags: gwt, gxt

When we run our application in GWT Dev Mode, we are getting serialization exceptions as shown below that we do not get if we run from outside of dev mode. Any ideas? Please note that the class MySDO in question extends from com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModel which is itself serializable & also has a public no parameter contructor

```
Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.foo.MySDO' was not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' and did not have a custom field serializer.For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = com.foo.MySDO@fd4410
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:610) [:]
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:129) [:]
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.serialize(Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.java:43) [:]
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:36) [:]
```

Comment: do you have an empty constructor MySDO() in that class?

Comment: Yes I do have an empty constructor. Additionally I also have a data member that is part of this class. It also extends from GXT BaseModel & has en empty constructor.

Answer (score 1):

May be com.foo.MySDO include some other not serialiseble type